# C# List<object> AddRange of DBNull.Value

Tags: c#, list, addrange

I would like to initialize a list with a given number of items, all with value DBNull.Value, is this possible via AddRange?

This code initializes as nulls and not DBNull.Value

```
_cellList = new List<object>(new DBNull[_columns.Count]);
```

Whereas this does the job correctly, but with a for loop:

```
_cellList = new List<object>();
for(int i = 0; i<_columns.Count; i++)
{
    _cellList.Add(DBNull.Value);
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Repeat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899(v=vs.110).aspx) in combination with `ToList`, like this:

```
_cellList = Enumerable
    .Repeat(DBNull.Value, _columns.Count)
    .Cast<object>()
    .ToList();
```

Note the use of `Cast<object>()`, which is necessary to construct `List<object>` instead of `List<DBNull>`.

Comment: that's sick! thanks a lot!